# hyperledger maximum number of organisations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is the maximum number of organisations you can have in Hyperledger fabric dependent on how many unoccupied port numbers you have on your server, to host the docker containers?

Answer (score 1):

In a real deployment, multiple organizations would not be hosted on the same physical machine(s).  So there is really no limit to the number of organizations which can be part of a single Hyperledger Fabric network.  As a matter of fact, there's no reason why there could not be a single Fabric network hosting all types of different organizations, business / use cases and/or channels.

In terms of trying to setup some type of demonstration / test network on a single set of machines, you are only limited by the physical / virtual resources of your compute.